# SharePoint 2016 server certificate expiration - Renewal

Tags: sharepoint-server, certificate

We have a SharePoint 2016 server farm with one front end, one application, and one Office Online server. On these servers, we have a wild card certificate that is going to expire in a few days. Before that, we want to update the new certificate in these servers.

Could anyone please provide me with the end-to-end process to update the certificate on the SharePoint 2016 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **SharePoint Server** itself you don't have to do anything other than updating certificate through IIS bindings.
Just make sure that your SP is being accessed directly by requesting Web Server, not through reverse proxy (and if it is used, then update there).

For **Workflow Manager**, make sure first that you're really have using your old wildcard certificate at WFM-farm by running `Get-WFFarm`, `Get-SBFarm` and `Get-WFOutboundCertificate` cmdlets and comparing that certs' thumbprints with your expiring one to determine which of those are really require to update.
There are 6 certificates (3 for ServiceBus and 3 for WorkflowManager) and usually some of them are self-signed (like *WorkflowOutbound* cert) and auto-generated.
Then, use `Set-SBCertificate`, `Set-WFCertificate` and `Set-WFNextOutboundCertificateReference` to update those ones that need it. For a detailed (and very order-dependent) process you can refer to one of these articles:

- http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm3.aspx ("*Reconfiguring Service Bus and Workflow Manager to use the new certificate*")
- https://dellenny.com/how-to-modify-the-workflow-manager-certificates-before-they-expire/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/whereismysolution/changing-my-workflow-manager-farm-certificates

For **Office Online Server** you can update your cert by running `Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -CertificateName` cmdlet specifying Friendly Name of new cert, imported in *Local Machine - Personal store*.

As always, after all manipulations it is recommended:

- Restart IIS
- Add new cert to SP trust
- [Clear SSL State](https://supportcenter.lexisnexis.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1084255/%7E/clear-ssl-state-on-microsoft-internet-explorer) in IE

Answer (score 0):

If you have a internet public facing SharePoint site that uses HTTPS that is hosted on premise and its certificate is due to be expired, then follow the complete steps below on the process involved with renewing a certificate on the SharePoint farm.

1. Create a CSR file – For more details, see “Step 1: Create a CSR
   File”
2. Send the client the CSR file to the end-user and get them to make a
   purchase order to renew their certificate through their vendor with
   the CSR file. For more details, see “Step 2: Ordering SSL
   Certificate”
3. Install and Configure SSL Certificate
4. Bind SSL Certificate in IIS

Please follow the complete guide here:

https://davidliong.wordpress.com/2019/04/15/renewing-sharepoint-certificates-on-premise/

Comment: We have already certificate have installed in the server certificate personal store, from that onwards we are looking for some references. Updating the iis binding will not work, we need to execute some set of PowerShell commands. We have SharePoint 2013 workflow manager installed in the WFE server.